# What is the best way to flag a model as inappropriate/spam in Django?

Tags: django, flags

I am new to Django and in my webapp I'd like the user to be able to flag a model as inappropriate. I've been using reuasable apps like django-voting and tagging but there is not much documentation for django-flag. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that any of the three can be used to flag a model as inappropriate. Do you have any specific considerations in mind that makes you prefer `django-flag`?

Comment: I was using the other apps as examples of resuable apps I am currently working with. I didn't consider them for use in flagging. Which app would you suggest I use to flag and how?

Comment: I could use the tagging app and when the user clicks the flag link I set a "dead" tag on that model. Does tagging allow multiple users to tag the same model with the same tag? I'd like to be able to count up how many times a certain model was flagged so I can know when to moderate them.

Comment: @knuckfubuck: I haven't used the tagging module so I can't answer the question. That said you might want to intercept each time a user tags something as dead and increment a count someplace. When the count crosses a threshold you can "kill" the offending item.